# Searching for a service that auto updates an Android app for QA purposes

Tags: android, apk, auto-update

When developing an app, there are lots of build versions to test.

The QA team would like the app to get updated automatically upon a new build.

As a developer, I'd like new builds to get uploaded automatically to such a service. This means I'd like such a service to support uploading new apk's via some kind of API (or script).

Anyone knows of such a service?

*** Google play alpha/beta, for example, would be a nice auto-upload service candidate if they supported uploading the apk via code/script, BUT Google play alpha/beta support only manual apk upload :(

Comment: Eventually went with hockeyapp. They have a separate app that notifies the testers if a new version was uploaded and enables installing it in 1 click.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of services available.

1. TestFlight (Stopping support for Android on 21/3/2014)
2. HockeyApp (Calling check for update which works fine) [HockeyApp.net](http://hockeyapp.net)
3. TestFairy (Didn't use properly but works similar like TestFlight) http://testfairy.com/

Answer (score 1):

DeployGate has an API to upload APKs: https://deploygate.com